# How to analyze the determinants of various inequality indexes over time?

Tags: distributions, decomposition, diversity

I have data concerning the distribution of income, at the individual level, i.e. I have for each individual income and some socio-demographic descriptors. I have this kind of data for several years, but for unrelated individuals (it is not panel data).
With this data I can calculate various inequality measures (e.g. Gini coefficient, D9/D1 ratio, relative poverty threshold (EU definition : 60% of the median income)).

My question is : how can I examine the effects of the sociodemographic determinants and more particularly the changes over time of these determinants on these indicators ? A question I would like to be able to answer is "what is the influence of the increasing share of single parents/increasing female participation in the workforce/the increase of the average schooling duration?" on these indexes of inequality.

One of the difficulty lies in the fact that these indexes depend on the whole distribution, not only on means. The most convincing literature I have found yet would be using unconditional quantile regressions / RIF regressions as descriped in [unconditional quantile regressions](http://www.nber.org/papers/t0339.pdf) and [Decomposition methods in economics](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjABahUKEwjEgtDEzfLIAhVDvRoKHShHDek&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.arts.ubc.ca%2Fnfortin%2Fw16045.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHKe2BiyXY6tJyM4UVOiy9ZJWjJvA&sig2=AxmGjlE-IHkxSz20-utn_A), but it seems a bit "heavy".

So

- Is this method actually making sense in my context ?
- Are there any other "obvious" methods I have missed ?

Comment: To me, the best way to analyze these questions would be to have enough information at the individual level to track *changes* in subjects' status on the relevant factors and how this impacts income. So, as people go from nonparent to parent as a function of marital status or from jobless to employed by gender, etc. What will be very hard to decompose is the confounding as a function of income, poverty, education, social status, etc., which are all correlated.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have panel data, it is different individuals each year

Comment: The pessimism here may or may not be justified. But it seems that the impact of group characteristics such as inequality is precisely your research question and you do at least have scope for measuring inequality in numerous different ways, as a large and still expanding literature indicates.

Comment: I am not sure I have fully understood your comment. I can measure inequality, but I would like to  decompose its evolutions over time in regard to the evolution of socio-demographic characteristics.
I would have prefered not to mention any particular method to know what method people think about, but my particular understanding of the literature would make me go towards RIF-regressions and unconditional quantile regressions, as in Firpo(2009), but it seems a bit "heavy", so I was wondering is there is better/simpler of it is actually needed.

Comment: Just mentioning Firpo (2009) and assuming that people recognise the reference is going to cut your readership down to a very few people who work in the same field. More crucially, open and general questions here usually backfire on the OP, as people are then just unclear about what you want and/or unable or unwilling to respond to what looks like a fishing expedition.  I am now confused too: title says "determinants of inequality" but the question itself seems all about the _consequences_ of inequality.

Comment: As yet, there are no answers here, only comments, so a rewrite seems implied to clarify what you seek. It's your choice, but I'd advise against anything that looks like "please give me some ideas for my project"; that's not the purpose of this forum.

Comment: I am not bilingual and try to do my best. It is edited, I hope it is better.

Comment: This sounds like a variant of macroeconomic trend analysis insofar as evolution of metrics of "inequality" are not decomposable down to the individual level. If this is correct, it would also require *many* years of macro information for estimation from sources such as the BLS, the UN or Gapminder.org. Given that, I don't see how possession of individual level information for a *few* years  is helpful. In fact, trying to reconcile this data with the stated objective may be more confusing than not.

Comment: Don't think the comments are "nitpicky" - it's important to help clarify questions to the point where they stand a reasonable chance of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: @DJohnson I have the data each year from 1996 to 2012, likely 2013. But my concern is definitely about micro-level analysis.

Comment: I agree that integrating the macro and micro levels is problematic. While the macro information seems well defined and populated, even 16 (or so) years of micro level data would capture roughly two business cycles, two or three economic downturns but only 1 large credit cycle -- all of which seem like factors you would want to control for in studying this topic. Of those concerns, it's the last one -- the credit cycle that ended with the "Great Recession" in 2007 -- that probably did the most to blur the harshest edges of income inequality by artificially inflating consumers' disposable income

Comment: I think I understand your point, but I am not sure what to make of it. I think most econometrics don't take that into account (not sure what the epistemologic value of that is though). For instance, Mincer's equations are often used, even on only one year, and without a general parameter concerning growth. Therefore, on that matter in a pluriannual perspective, I could compare the evolution of the influence of diploma over the years (I guess currently the coefficient is supposed to have increased). I would like to do things like that, but one of my concerns is my outcome is an inequality index

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Mincer's equation, that was a new one. I still don't see how Mincer helps you with inequality measures. Not being an economist may put my comments into the "atheoretical." I would refer you to the work of *behavioral* economists such as David Laibson who estimated a consumption function based on the Panel Survey of Income Dynamics using things like propensity to leverage credit card debt as a function of intertemporal choice and time discounting, here... http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/laibson/files/hyperbolic_discounting_and_consumption.pdf?m=1360041289

Comment: The PSID is a representative, longitudinal panel of US consumers originating in the 1970s up to the present and might be a much better source of information for your analysis.

Comment: Your concerns have been weighing on me so I browsed the link to the *Decomposition methods* paper you provided. You've got your work cut out for you! One obvious recommendation would be to start simple and build up to increasinly complex analyses. I do agree with you that approaches leveraging quantile regressions seem best suited if you go the "decomposition" route. Second, I still question the value of only ~16 years of individual level information for some of the truly long term trends of interest to you: single parents, women in the workforce, years of schooling, etc.

Comment: Section 6.2 - Panel Data on p. 97 of that document discusses the additional interpretative and analytic power possible with longitudinal panel information beyond decomposition. Again, the US PSID seems particularly well suited for your analysis as it originates in the late 60s in a country with wide gaps in income inequality, indeed, some of the widest in the world. The only trend it might not capture well is "years of schooling" since education in the US has been at high levels dating back well into the 20th c. It is available free for download here  https://psidonline.isr.umich.edu/

Comment: It looks like this thread is dead. Regardless, here's a link to a NY Fed article studying the impact of quantitative easing on regional inequality...  http://libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org/2015/11/how-did-quantitative-easing-interact-with-regional-inequality.html#.VkDgctKrRkq

Comment: It is not, I just unfortunately have to focus on other things at work so I have less time to think and ho into details about this subject. But I will be back with longer answers (and will delete this comment)

Comment: Came across this paper by Phillip Tobler on the neural representations of inequality... here's a link to a google search on this topic ... https://www.google.com/search?q=Neural+Representation+of+Inequality&oq=Neural+Representation+of+Inequality&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=Neural+Representation+of+Inequality+tobler

Comment: The 2016 World Economic Forum is underway and inequality is a key topic. Check out #inequality for more...